# Custom adapter fails in sails v0.10

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

My adapter fails to register in Sails v0.10. From what I can see in the [docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/Tutorial%3a%20custom-adapters.md), registerCollection() is still the adapter method which is supposed to handle collection registration. However, sails complaining that the adapter is not compatible with the current version (0.10.0-rc4).

> error: Is this a valid Sails/Waterline adapter?  The following error
>   was encountered ::
>   error: Adapter is not compatible with the current version of Sails.

This is strange because I created the adapter using v0.10 via the `sails generate adapter` command. Anyone have any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the docs (and the generator!) are in flux.  `registerCollection` is no longer valid.  I'd take a look at the `adapter.js` from the [sails-disk](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-disk/blob/master/lib/adapter.js) adapter as a good basis for where to start.

Comment: Yea, it looks like `registerCollection` has moved to `registerConnection`.